# pushing code from local server repo to cloud repo

Tags: git

I am very new to git and I have two repositories one in local server and another is in cloud gitlab.com, with different folder names but the code is same in both. Now I want to push my code which I cloned from local server(folder name 'code') to cloud gitlab(here folder name xs-misc) how can I do it?

Comment: You'd probably benefit the most from reading an actual tutorial or documentation, such as https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes .

Answer (score 0):

A git repo doesn't care about the name of the folder it's in. You can go ahead and set the remote path (which contains `xs-misc`).